# pysnmp not able to receive trap from different machine

Tags: python-2.7, pysnmp

Instead of localhost IP , I have My VM ip (eth0-192.168.12.20) to receive trap notification, I am not receiving any traps if generate one from outside the VM(I am using snmptrap command from another machine) but I can see SNMP data when I do tcpdump on VM interface eth0.
If I generate trap from same machine using snmptrap command I can see trap data via PySNMP trap receiver script.

Option's tried:
1. Tried binding the port to 0.0.0.0 to receive trap from any machine
2. Enabled debugging option in pysnmp to get some idea to solve the issue. There is no info generated when sending snmptrap from outside machine

[The closest scenario](https://sourceforge.net/p/pysnmp/mailman/message/35313236/) similar to my question is present in the following link which does not have final solution.

Code:
SNMP v1 and v2c:

```
from pysnmp.carrier.asynsock.dispatch import AsynsockDispatcher
from pysnmp.carrier.asynsock.dgram import udp, udp6
from pyasn1.codec.ber import decoder
from pysnmp.proto import api
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import ntfrcv

from pysnmp import debug
debug.setLogger(debug.Debug("all"))

### SNMPv2c/SNMPv1 setup
### Callback function for receiving notifications
def v2cv1CallBackFunc(snmpEngine, stateReference, contextEngineId, contextName,
                      varBinds, cbCtx):
    transportDomain, transportAddress = snmpEngine.msgAndPduDsp.getTransportInfo(stateReference)
    print transportDomain, transportAddress
    # Get an execution context...
    execContext = snmpEngine.observer.getExecutionContext(
        'rfc3412.receiveMessage:request'
    )

    # ... and use inner SNMP engine data to figure out peer address
    print('Notification from %s, ContextEngineId "%s", ContextName "%s"'
                          %('@'.join([str(x) for x in execContext['transportAddress']]),
                            contextEngineId.prettyPrint(), contextName.prettyPrint()))

    for name, val in varBinds:
        print('%s = %s' % (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))


# Create SNMP engine with autogenernated engineID and pre-bound
# to socket transport dispatcher
snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine()

# SNMPv1/2c setup
# SecurityName <-> CommunityName mapping
config.addV1System(snmpEngine, 'my-area', "public")

# Specify security settings per SecurityName (SNMPv2c -> 1)
config.addTargetParams(snmpEngine, 'my-creds', 'my-area', 'noAuthNoPriv', 1)

# Transport setup
# UDP over IPv4, first listening interface/port
config.addSocketTransport(
    snmpEngine,
    udp.domainName + (1, ),
    udp.UdpSocketTransport().openServerMode(('0.0.0.0', 162))
)

# Register SNMP Application at the SNMP engine
ntfrcv.NotificationReceiver(snmpEngine, v2cv1CallBackFunc)

snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)  # this job would never finish

# Run I/O dispatcher which would receive queries and send confirmations
try:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
except:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
    raise
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue with the help from my IT team. Basically the API is working perfectly.

The firewalld application is not allowing the packets to pass through. So after I added the SNMP port to firewall exception list, it made my code working.

Commands I used:

- sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=161-162/udp --zone=public --permanent
- sudo systemctl restart network
- sudo systemctl reload firewalld